# How to convert array to separate value in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable

I am using `DataTable.Rows.Add()` Method to add rows, and I'd like to change an array of double to separate values to match the columns.

e.g. `table.Rows.Add('Name', 'Id', arrayOfDouble, anotherValue)`

where arrayOfDouble has one or more value, and each one is a column.

Can I do this in C#? I think it's called flatten or something.

Thank you!

Comment: what happens if it's missing a value? if it has an extra one? I doubt you can do it straight away, you can probably do it with a custom method ...

Comment: @Noctis The array has the same length as the one I added as columns, so length is not the problem. Yes I can add values one by one, I just think there should be an easier method.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but from what I understand from your question, I would have done:

```
//Assuming you have a DataTable like this:
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Clear();
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("ID");
dt.Columns.Add("double 1");
dt.Columns.Add("double 2");
dt.Columns.Add("double 3");
dt.Columns.Add("some int");

// And a double array like this:
var double_array = new double[] {2.4,4.3,48.8};
```

I would have a method like this:

```
object[] prepare_row(string s1, string s2, double[] double_array, object some_object) {
    // Adding first 2 entries
    List<object> temp_list = new List<object> {s1, s2};
    // Adding your double arary
    foreach (var val in double_array)
    {
        temp_list.Add(val);
    }
    // Adding your anotherValue
    temp_list.Add(some_object);

    return  temp_list.ToArray();
}
```

And add your array like:

```
dt.Rows.Add( prepare_row("Noctis", "1", double_array, 7) );
```

Comment: Thank you, this is just like what I have done, but I wonder if there is a way to flatten the array.

Comment: You can use linq `SelectMany` to "flatten" some lists, but I doubt it'll help you out on this one ...